# Get count of tuples in list regardless of elements orders

Tags: python, list, count, tuples

I have a list of tuples that looks something like this:

```
my_list = [(1,12),(12,1),(12,1),(20,15),(7,8),(15,20)]
```

I want to get a count of the number combinations regardless of the order. For example, if it were to be simply printed, I'd like the output to be:

```
1,12 = 3
20,15 = 2
7,8 = 1
```

Basically, I have a list of connections but the direction doesn't matter, so 1 to 12 is the same as 12 to 1.

I have been working on this for a while and can't come up with a clean solution. Everything I've come up with would have to check for both directions, but the list of tuples is random, so covering every possibility would be ridiculous. I could easily count the unique tuples with set or something, but again, every solution for the "bi-directional" count I've thought about is sloppy.

I feel like this shouldn't be very hard, but I am thoroughly at brain fry from working on this so long. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Dont name lists list, it overrides a builtin name

Comment: I didn't, this just an example. Do you have any idea on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can swap all positions by size and then use `collections.counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
l = [(1,12),(12,1),(12,1),(20,15),(7,8),(15,20)]
new_l = Counter([[(b, a), (a, b)][a < b] for a, b in l])
for a, b in new_l.items():
  print('{},{}:{}'.format(*(list(a)+[b])))
```

Output:

```
15,20:2
7,8:1
1,12:3
```

Comment: Perfect! I've never used counter before. I knew there was a clean way to do this that I was missing. If I could up this answer I would, but I'm still under 15 rep. Thank you!!

Comment: @neural_nomad Glad to help!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I believe its either because some find it's not very readable to use a bool as index or because you are generating a list and two tuple on each iteration instead of relying on some built-in. In any case, I do think it is not a very pythonic answer. Not worth a downvote in my book, but still.

Comment: Or somebody is just on a downvote spree. Even I got one for no reason.

Comment: No idea. This solution worked well. I guess those suggested after are more concise? But I don't think people should downvote this as it worked well.

Comment: Downvote should usually be used only for answers that are plain wrong, very unclear, or getting old to notify the poster. But ghost downvoters happen... it's annoying and useless without criticism, but what can we do...

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Agreed. Oh well.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `collections.Counter`, normalizing your elements with `sorted` first.

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [(1,12),(12,1),(12,1),(20,15),(7,8),(15,20)]

count = Counter(tuple(sorted(t)) for t in lst)
# output: Counter({(1, 12): 3, (15, 20): 2, (7, 8): 1})
```

You can then print like so.

```
for value, amount in count.items():
    print(value, '=', amount)

# Prints: 
# (1, 12) = 3
# (15, 20) = 2
# (7, 8) = 1
```

Comment: This is at least an `n^2log(n)`  solution with `sorted` at each iteration. I would consider a more efficient method of organizing each tuple.

Comment: Python's [Timsort](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) is very efficient on short, already sorted sequences. And calling sorted will make that all happen in C, so it will likely be more efficient. Also, it is not n^2log(n) since tuples have a fixed length, they do not have a length of n. Thus it is simply O(n)

Comment: Granted that the tuples in the input are small, thus, `sorted` in this case is not a big deal, however, it is worth pointing out the efficiency would decrease for large input. But then I suppose one would have to use `sorted`.

Comment: Yes, you cannot go around sorting if you want to normalize the tuples.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of sorting the tuples before the count. Seems extremely simple now. Glad there is stack overflow for when you've completely fried yourself by working an issue for too long!!

Comment: I just want to point out that it is actually wrong that we cannot normalize without sorting. We could count occurence of elements in tuples. But I think that would be overcomplicated for what we are trying to accomplish here and could not be one-lined.

Answer (score 1):

First you can sort your list

```
lst2 = [tuple(sorted(i)) for i in lst]
```

Then you can use `set()` to find the unique values in this list and count their occurence.

```
count = {}
for i in set(lst2):
    num = len([1 for j in lst2 if j == i])
    count.update({i:num})
print(count)
```

> {(1, 12): 3, (7, 8): 1, (15, 20): 2}

Answer (score 1):

You can try simple approach without importing anything like this:

```
my_list = [(1,12),(12,1),(12,1),(20,15),(7,8),(15,20)]

count={}
for i in my_list:
    if tuple(sorted(i)) not in count:
        count[tuple(sorted(i))]=1
    else:
        count[tuple(sorted(i))]+=1

print(count)
```

output:

```
{(15, 20): 2, (7, 8): 1, (1, 12): 3}
```